# Python POO tienda de moto

Tags: python

Hola estoy practicando con un ejercicio de POO quiero hacer 2 métodos uno tenga los datos de las motos tipo, precio y marca y otro que imprima dichos valores pero a la hora de llamar el método establecer_valores me da error alguna solución porfa. que me falta o cual es el error que estoy cometiendo?

```
class TiendaMoto:
nombre = "Tienda de motos" # Atributos

#Metodos
def __init__(self,tipo,precio,marca):
    self.tipo = tipo
    self.precio = precio
    self.marca = marca    

def establecer_valores(self):
    self.moto1 = TiendaMoto("Estandar","$1000","Bera")
    self.moto2 = TiendaMoto("Deportiva","$2000","Yamaha")
    self.moto3 = TiendaMoto("Todo terreno","$1500","BMW")

datos = TiendaMoto
print(datos.nombre)
print(datos.establecer_valores())
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Comment: ¿Por qué estás intentando imprimir la llamada a un método?. Creo que tú error es ese, que estás intentado hacer el `print` a algo que no es un string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mejor haz lo siguiente:

```
class TiendaMoto:
   nombre = "Tienda de motos" # Atributos
  
   def establecer_valores(tipo,precio,marca):
       print(tipo)
       print(precio)
       print(marca)
     
datos = TiendaMoto
print(datos.nombre)
# y llamas al métodos todas las veces que necesites
datos.establecer_valores("Estandar","$1000","Bera")
datos.establecer_valores("Deportiva","$2000","Yamaha")
datos.establecer_valores("Todo terreno","$1500","BMW")
```

Comment: No debería ser necesario... el valor `self` es inyectado por python cuando lo llamas desde un objeto. Es decir, python ve que estás llamando al método a través de la instancia `datos` y ese es el valor que toma el `self`. El error que le da es que está intentando imprimir un método.... que no devuelve absolutamente nada!

Comment: Gracias me funciono

Comment: Si no entiendo muy bien lo de self

Comment: Es una buena idea explicar un poco el código de tu respuesta, para que otros futuros usuarios puedan ver cual era el problema y adaptarlo a sus necesidades.